# Android AlertDialog onDismiss get user choice

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Consider the following AlertDialog:

```
pizzaOrderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    pizzaOrderDialog.setTitle("One last thing:");
    pizzaOrderDialog.setMessage("Would you like black or green olives?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Black", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    orderPizza("black");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ok! Thanks!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Green", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    orderPizza("green");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ok! Thanks!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    alertD = pizzaOrderDialog.create();
```

It's possible that the user also chooses to dismiss the dialog by touching anywhere on the screen, not clicking "Black" or "Green". What I want is to "catch" this case and get an indication of this scenario in onDismiss:

```
alertD.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //TODO tell if dialog result was dialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE
            // or maybe dialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE ?
        }
    });
```

What's the best practice here? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `setOnCancelListener()`?

Comment: Thank you. Basic stuff. Should I just remove this question?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was something going awry with your use of `setOnCancelListener()`. Answering your own question here seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, as pointed out by @CommonsWare, I needed to use `setOnCancelListener` here.